# Manifest file format for installing a Library package

Tags: joomla-3.4, extensions, libraries

I cant't able to find a Joomla help page explaining how a library type extension can be installed.

[Joomla Manifest Files](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files)

I refer the above URL and don't find any further explanation on library files.

Can someone explain how to create the library extension so that it can be installed via Joomla installation manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a folder structure like so:

```
/my_library.xml
/my_library
  file_1
  file_2
  etc
```

Then in your **my_library.xml** file, add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="library" method="upgrade" version="3.4">
    <name>My Library</name>
    <libraryname>mylibrary</libraryname>
    <author>Malaiselvan</author>
    <creationDate>September 2015</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2015</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
    <authorEmail>example@example.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.example.com</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Some description</description>

    <files>
        <folder>my_library</folder>
    </files>
</extension>
```

Once all is done, zip everything up and install it like you would any other extension.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. It works great.  Can you please let me know how the language file can be used? I do not want to hard code the name author name etc...